# Website reverse engineering, AJAX response

Tags: php, html, ajax, google-chrome-devtools, reverse-engineering

I am trying to understand how website security works & how data flows at the backend of the website

Say I access the link
https://www.iimjobs.com/search/IT-0-0-0-1.html

It sends an AJAX query through getajaxresponse.php & gets a list of jobs that I can see from google chrome browser inspect option as shown below.

[Chrome - Inspect Element - Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGMJ5.jpg)

If you go to Network=>XHR=>Headers=>select the getajaxresponse.php & scroll down in the headers pane you get a list of job ids.

As we scroll down in the main website, subsequent HTML pages (https://www.iimjobs.com/search/IT-0-0-100-2.html etc) are called which sends next AJAX calls & keeps getting new job IDs as seen from the chrome inspect tool.

**My question:**
How the website is populating the remaining details of the job from the job ID.

[Job information displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6mqg.jpg)

For example, the first listed job has a unique URL which contains the first job ID (614482)
https://www.iimjobs.com/j/ocwen-it-project-manager-10-15-yrs-614482.html?ref=sp

How did the page get or build this URL? location? Job posting date? in the webpage view.

Comment: It makes *another* AJAX request, which is returning a big block of HTML. Filter your network inspector to XHRs and you'll see it.

Comment: The big block of HTML that you see is the GET request for next page. My view is that first I GET /IT-0-0-0-1.html which in turn POST getajaxresponse.php. This POST gets the JOB IDs & populates the webpage; Next as I scroll down, the AJAX  GET /IT-0-0-100-2.html which in turn POST getajaxresponse.php to get new set of Job IDs,  This continues to get the job list populated, but I still do not see how the webpage is able to get the URL,location, date from the jobid.

Comment: It's not using the job ID for that. The job details are all in the `GET` call. The `POST` is for something else - probably storing which jobs were viewed. I'll bet their system tells employers "your job was viewed x times".

Comment: Understood. Do you know of any good tutorial on learning through these browser developer tools?

Answer (score -1):

It loads HTML page with job details. If you want to analyze the javascript code, please take a look at the following js file https://static.iimjobs.com/resources/js/javascript.min.js?ver=1536311800.
Some HTML elements have an attribute data-jobid="..." and this is referenced from javascript code to do some extra processing (I guess this is to toggle some icons on/off).